# how to send array from one controller to another controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function driver_list_odr(){
 if($this->session->userdata("pharmacy_email") != null){

            if($this->input->post('order_list'))
            {
                $this->load->model('registration');
                $order_list = array(
                                        "o_id"=>$this->input->post('order_list'),
                                        "p_id"=>$this->session->userdata("pharmacy_email"),
                                        "s_dt"=>$this->input->post('sdate'),
                                        "e_dt"=>$this->input->post('edate')
                                    ); 
                if(!empty($order_list)){
                    $this->drvr_odr_exel($order_list); //passing data into another function
                 } else {
                    echo "Didn't get value from post";
                 }
               echo $this->registration->get_driver_list_odr($order_list);
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('pharmacy/login');
        }
    }
public function drvr_odr_exel($order_list = array()){
    if(is_array($order_list) && count($order_list) > 0){
        print_r($order_list);
    } else {
         echo "No result found";
    }
}
```

> it's display No result found

Comment: before `if(!empty($order_list)){` do a `var_dump($order_list)`. there is also no need for checking if `is_array` since you declared the variable has to be array `$order_list=array()`

Comment: both functions are from the same controller or the second one is from a different controller?

Comment: Ok, Your question should be -> how to pass array from one function to another

Comment: @AbhishekVishwakarma yes

Comment: can you recheck same code giving proper result.

Comment: Your code is working fine. The reason, you are not able to print data can be -> Your if statement is not getting satistified. The working code you can see here -> http://codepad.org/XYIDBkoW